# Gulp.js: How to dynamically concatenate subdirectory files, but not files in main directory

Tags: javascript, gulp

Using Gulp.js, I want to be able to be able to compile individual files in my `js` folder as normal, but concatenate content placed in subdirectories and assign the folder name to the concatenated file. (there's also some linting and minification going on)

**Example Source**

```
|-- js/
|   |-- main/
|   |   |-- script1.js
|   |   |-- script2.js
|   |   |-- script3.js
|   |-- detects/
|   |   |-- scriptA.js
|   |   |-- scriptB.js
|   |   |-- scriptC.js
|   |-- myplugin.js
|   |-- myplugin2.js
```

**Example Output**

```
|-- js/
|   |-- myplugin.js
|   |-- myplugin.min.js
|   |-- myplugin2.js
|   |-- myplugin2.min.js
|   |-- main.js
|   |-- main.min.js
|   |-- detects.js
|   |-- detects.min.js
```

**What I've tried**

```
gulp.task('scripts', ['clean'], function() {
    return gulp.src('src/js/*')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe(tap(function (file, t) {
            if ( file.stat.isDirectory() ) {
                var name = file.relative + '.js';
                return gulp.src(file.path + '/*.js')
                    .pipe(concat(name))
                    .pipe(header(banner.full, { package : package }))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.output))
                    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min.' + Date.now() }))
                    .pipe(uglify())
                    .pipe(header(banner.min, { package : package }))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.output));
            }
        }))
        .pipe(header(banner.full, { package : package }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.output))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min.' + Date.now() }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(header(banner.min, { package : package }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.output));
});
```

This actually works, but I don't like that I'm repeating code both in and after `gulp-tap`. Ideally I should be able to do something like this and have it feed back into the stream:

```
gulp.task('scripts', ['clean'], function() {
    return gulp.src('src/js/*')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe(tap(function (file, t) {
            if ( file.stat.isDirectory() ) {
                var name = file.relative + '.js';
                return gulp.src(file.path + '/*.js')
                    .pipe(concat(name));
            }
        }))
        .pipe(header(banner.full, { package : package }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.output))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min.' + Date.now() }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(header(banner.min, { package : package }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.output));
});
```

However, the subdirectory files are never compiled to the `dest` this way. other things I've tried that have not worked either:

**1**

```
.pipe(tap(function (file, t) {
    if ( file.stat.isDirectory() ) {
        var name = file.relative + '.js';
        t.through(gulp.src(file.path + '/*.js')
            .pipe(concat(name)));
    }
}))
```

**2**

```
.pipe(tap(function (file, t) {
    if ( file.stat.isDirectory() ) {
        var name = file.relative + '.js';
        .pipe(gulp.src(file.path + '/*.js')
            .pipe(concat(name)));
    }
}))
```

**3**

```
.pipe(tap(function (file, t) {
    if ( file.stat.isDirectory() ) {
        var name = file.relative + '.js';
        gulp.src(file.path + '/*.js')
            .pipe(concat(name));
    }
}))
```

**4**

```
.pipe(tap(function (file, t) {
    var scripts;
    if ( file.stat.isDirectory() ) {
        var name = file.relative + '.js';
        scripts = gulp.src(file.path + '/*.js')
            .pipe(concat(name));
    }
    return scripts;
}))
```

I've got functioning code so I'm not totally stuck, but I know there's a better way to do this. I would also like to be checking for a `.js` extension before running my uglifying and minifying (something covered for styles already because I'm only grabbing `.scss` files). Any insights here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [lazypipe](https://github.com/OverZealous/lazypipe) to build up reusable processing pipelines.

Once you've identified the "reusable" behaviour you can convert it into a reusable block and invoke it multiple times.

In your case the repeated processing are these calls:

```
.pipe(header(banner.full, { package : package }))
.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.output))
.pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min.' + Date.now() }))
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(header(banner.min, { package : package }))
.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.output));
```

So convert the calls into a reusable pipeline (see note at the bottom):

```
var lazypipe = require('lazypipe');
//...
var process = lazypipe()
    .pipe(header, banner.full, { package : package })
    .pipe(gulp.dest, 'paths.scripts.output')
    .pipe(rename, { suffix: '.min.' + Date.now() })
    .pipe(uglify)
    .pipe(header, banner.min, { package : package })
    .pipe(gulp.dest, paths.scripts.output);
```

And then you can use it multiple times:

```
gulp.task('scripts', ['clean'], function() {
    //...
    return gulp.src('src/js/*')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe(tap(function (file, t) {
            if ( file.stat.isDirectory() ) {
                var name = file.relative + '.js';
                return gulp.src(file.path + '/*.js')
                    .pipe(concat(name))
                    .pipe(handle);
                    .pipe(process())  // <----- here
            }
        }))
        .pipe(process())  // <----- and here
});
```

**Everything together:**

```
gulp.task('scripts', ['clean'], function() {
    // Define reusable pipeline.
    var process = lazypipe()
        .pipe(header, banner.full, { package : package })
        .pipe(gulp.dest, 'paths.scripts.output')
        .pipe(rename, { suffix: '.min.' + Date.now() })
        .pipe(uglify)
        .pipe(header, banner.min, { package : package })
        .pipe(gulp.dest, paths.scripts.output);

    return gulp.src('src/js/*')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe(tap(function (file, t) {
            if ( file.stat.isDirectory() ) {
                var name = file.relative + '.js';
                return gulp.src(file.path + '/*.js')
                    .pipe(concat(name))
                    .pipe(handle);
                    .pipe(process())  // <----- use it here
            }
        }))
        .pipe(process())  // <----- and here
});
```

**NOTE:**
lazypipe uses lazy initialisation so the calls to `.pipe()` are different to regular Gulp streams.

Instead of calling the plugin like this: `.pipe(header(banner.full, { package : package }))`

You pass *all* as parameters to pipe: `.pipe(header, banner.full, { package : package })`

Comment: Another useful library is gulp-if, which lets you do conditional processing in your streams: https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if

Comment: Thanks. I had looked into `gulp-if` as well. Where it fell short for me: I really want to be able to grab the subdirectory name and use that as the concatenated file name. Your solution looks like it will work, but from what I've read about `gulp-tap`, I should be able to pass the new concatenated file back into the stream. https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-tap